# Не запускается jar файл на другом ПК

Tags: java, jar

Я новичок в программировании, написал программу, которая запускается как у меня в IntellIJ IDEA, так и в экспортированном виду (jar) на моём ПК. **Проблема:** Этот же jar не запускается на других ПК из-за какой-то ошибки (фото). Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы jar, который я скидываю другим людям, у них открывался за два клика (как у меня?).

Сама ошибка при открытии jar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный проект я оставил на Яндекс диске, посмотрите: https://yadi.sk/d/g5bxxOGWLovavA

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: нужен исходный код, а не jar

Comment: Небось скомпилирована под Java 14, а запускать на других ПК пытаетесь с помощью Java 8.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а где можно узнать под какую версию Java я скомпилировал свою программу? Наверное вы правы

Comment: В настройках проекта.

Comment: у вас там просто вакханалия статики. сделайте что-то с ней. поверьте. это важнее, чем запустить джаврник на другом компе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в IntellIJ IDEA настройках проекта указать версию сборки java 8 и пересоберите проект

```
File -> Project Structure -> Project: Project language level = 8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.
```

Возможно у вас установлен более свежая версия JDK (выше чем 1.8)

Другими словами, программа компилируется на Java 9 или выше, а на другом компьютере стоит более ранняя версия Java 8

версию JDK можно узнать выполнив команду в консоли

```
javac -version
```